# C# submit a form with captcha

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a very small app that will send a contact form.

this is my code so far.

**Html** (very very basic). Note - captcha is dynamic

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="email" type="text" />
    <div class="captcha"></div>
    <input name="captcha" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**C#** - I'm able to send the form with POST, but without the captcha

```
    string URI = "http://localhost/contact.php";
    string myParameters = "name=John&email=info@contact.com&captcha=???">;

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
    }
```

I want to display the captcha image and a textbox below it, in my app.
Is this possible?